# Wordpress Custom Rewrite Rule Returns 404 When Current Page Past 9

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a custom rewrite rule for "catalog" pages on my website to display the items within the specified catalog. Everything works great except the pagination which mysteriously returns a 404 error page if the user tries to navigate to a page greater than page 9. Below is the entire rewrite code. Other archives on the website have no issue with pages past page 9 so I feel like this must have something to do with the regex in my rewrite rule, but I'm lost as to what it could be.

```
function x_rewrite_rule_form_submissions()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%catalog%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('catalog/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?catalog=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule('catalog/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?catalog=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'x_rewrite_rule_form_submissions', 10, 0);
```

UPDATE: Using the Debug This plugin, I've found that WP_Query is attempting to run the main query on post_type="post" with the pagination information in the URL. My theory is that it's this query that is resulting in Wordpress returning a 404 error message. How can I overwrite/disable this main query?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 100, 10
```

Comment: what is the actual requested URL when you have a 404? (the rewritten one)

Comment: @Kaddath http://website.dev/catalog/example-catalog-entry-name/page/11/

Comment: As a quick update, I believe the issue has to do with the fact that Wordpress is trying to use the pagination number in a query on posts but there aren't more than 9 pages of posts. So maybe I need to figure out how to stop Wordpress from running its normal query on /catalog pages?

Comment: this one is the original URL, the rewritten one should begin by `index.php?catalog=...`. You can read the requested url in the console when you have a 404

Comment: Sorry, here's the rewritten one: index.php?catalog=example-catalog-entry-name&paged=11

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've solved the issue though I'm not sure it's the best solution so any feedback is appreciated! What I ended up doing was using pre_get_posts to alter the post_type so that the main Wordpress query request was using post_type="items" instead of post_type="post" on all catalog pages. Because of how many "items" there are in the database, no amount of pagination would ever result in a 404. Hope this helps people!

```
function alter_catalog_query( $query ) {
    $uri = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && isset($uri[1]) ) {
        if ( $uri[1] == 'catalog')
            $query->set('post_type','items');
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_catalog_query' );
```

Comment: ah, i didn't understand that the rewritten URL was for a custom query. I guess your solution works, but maybe it relies on something that could be wrong one day (more wp items than catalog items). In terms of code reuse, could lead to problems one day.. maybe something like `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 0 );` would be cleaner if it works?